# Share Integer globally

Tags: java, netty

I'm learing `Netty` and i'm trying to implement a simple counter, where all the clients shares an `Integer` and they input a number and the `Integer` value increments by that number.

Here is my code:

`Server.java`

```
package nettyincvalue;

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server {

    private int port;
    private Integer value;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        this.value = 0;
    }

    public void run(){

        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {

            ServerBootstrap server = new ServerBootstrap();

            server.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                  .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                  .childHandler(new ServerInit(this.value))
                  .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                  .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);


            ChannelFuture f = server.bind(port).sync();

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();


        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server(12345).run();
    }

}
```

`ServerInit.java`

```
package nettyincvalue;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;

public class ServerInit extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    private Integer value;

    public ServerInit(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast(new ServerHandler(this.value));

    }

}
```

`ServerHandler.java`

```
package nettyincvalue;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;

public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private Integer value;

    public ServerHandler(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

        String s = (String) msg;

        try {

            Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.length() - 1));
            this.value += i;
            System.out.println("Value its now: " + this.value);

        } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
            System.out.println("Not a number received");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        System.err.println(cause.getMessage());
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Individually, its working, when a client inputs via `nc` a number it increments but its not globally, i mean when a different client starts, the counter its set to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable doesn't have proper synchronization; it should generally be declared `volatile` to make sure that all threads see updated values, and you'll need to synchronize the blocks where you're using it. However, in your case, using an `AtomicInteger` will be simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know about AtomicInteger. But since this is an academic exercise, i solved this problem encapsulating an int inside my own class and it works, i only get this problem when using int or Integer. Just a quick question, will i have concurreny problems with this solution or i'll need to synchronize the increment method?

Comment: Right, Java Integers are immutable objects and it doesn't make a sence to share it.

Comment: @JoséRicardoRibeiro You'll still have the problem with the classic read(threadA)-read(threadB)-update(threadA)-update(threadB, but loses threadA's update) scenario. That's exactly what `AtomicInteger#addAndGet()` avoids. As a note, `AtomicInteger` *is* a part of the core Java library since Java 5, so make sure that you can't still use it.